# How to repeat click event on continue pressing in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, input, mouseevent

Here I have `plus` and `minus` image which is used to increasing or decreasing value of input successfully. Here is **[Working JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/91/)**

I want if user continue pressing key for increasing/decreasing it should be performed accordingly rather than by clicking again and again. Is that possible? If yes then what I have to change?

**Note:**  HTML5 `<input type="number">`  works perfectly but I don't want to use that due to compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/104/)

```
$(function () {
    var interval;
    $('.add').on('mousedown',function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        debugger
      var $qty=$this.parent().parent().find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    },500); 
}).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}).on('mouseout',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){

    }).on('mousedown',function(e) {
         var $this = $(this);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var $qty= $this.parent().parent().find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    },500); 
}).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}).on('mouseout',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

});
```

Edit: Added mouseout event also. Thanks for pointing it out @Yorick

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted.. Thank you so much I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: You need to track mouseout as well because if the mouse moves away from the +/- images while held down you won't get the mouseup event on your image DOM Element - you will get a mouseout though.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually you could trigger on a mousedown event and then repeat every n milliseconds until you receive a mouseup event.

That is on a mousedown you perform your increment or decrement action and then install a timer than runs every n milliseconds using setInterval(). When you receive the mouseup event you kill the timer.

Comment: OK, here is a modified JSFiddle that auto-increments every 1/2 second the mouse is held down. Auto-decrementing is left as an exercise: http://jsfiddle.net/yf3axa39/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should create flag variable which is set to true when mouse is over button and mouse button is pressed. Then check that variable periodically by creating function and using setTimeout function. In the function check the flag and increase/decrease the correct value accordingly.